# Modal fullscreen is aligned to the left

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

My fullscreen modal is aligned to the left. Centered property does not solve it. I have a row of the grid that dynamically displays a series of Cards. Each Card has the modal associated, so when you click the Card the modal opens with information from the Card.

This is the grid where i render it

```
<Grid.Column key={this.props.sensorid} width={4}>
        <Card
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ modalOpen: true });
          }}
          color={color}
          header={String(porce) + " %"}
          description={this.props.sensorname}
          meta={nivelUno + " mm"}
        />

          <ModalSensor
            sensorWell={this.props.sensorWell}
            sensorName={this.props.sensorConPrefijo}
            sensorId = {this.props.sensorid}
            modalOpen={this.state.modalOpen}
            handleClose={() => {
              this.setState({ modalOpen: false });
            }}
          />

      </Grid.Column>
```

This is the modal

```
export default class ModalSensor extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Modal
        centered={true}
        open={this.props.modalOpen}
        onClose={this.props.handleClose}
        closeOnEscape={true}
        size={"Fullscreen"}
      >
        <Modal.Header>Nivel del sensor {this.props.sensorName}</Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Content>

            <Sensor sensorwell={this.props.sensorWell} sensorcodigo={this.props.sensorName}/>

        </Modal.Content>
        <Modal.Actions>
          <Button
            inverted
            color="orange"
            type="button"
            icon="checkmark"
            labelPosition="right"
            onClick={this.props.handleClose}
            content="Cerrar"
          />
        </Modal.Actions>
      </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Modal aligned to the left]

Answer (score 0):

that's a common problem when using more than one css library just inspect your element with your browser dev tool and try to figure it out or else past it here None can help you (probably) because it's a css problem and you haven't any css here.

Good luck man.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this type of layout bug, but I fixed it by adding a custom class to `<div class="ui fullscreen modal transition visible active" />`

```
.customClass {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```